# How to submit captcha by cURL

Tags: curl, captcha

I'm working on a project to create a third party site where we show a captcha image originated by the original site and a user has to write the text on the captcha image in an input form. Then we send the form via POST method using cURL. But it doesn't work for the captcha. I have searched a lot on web and 80% of the posts I've gone through say that it's impossible, while I found some other posts saying they've got success with no description. I'm curious to know whether it's possible or not. If possible then can you help me to do it please?

We don't need captcha-break or something like this. Input for capthca is made manually by user. We only need to send it using cURL to the original site.

Thanks in advance :-)

Here is the code, I try now:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
$name=$_POST['name'];
$captcha=$_POST['code'];
$data_pass = "user=".$name."&code=".$captcha;

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_pass);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/cookiefile.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/cookiefile.txt");


$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Have you attempt to reproduce the exchange by looking at the network activity from Firebug? Record-and-(smart)-replay usually will work, since there is no way to tell them apart.

Comment: MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Never blame someone using "people like you" without knowing in details.

Comment: Download the rapidleech script, then find how they processing the captcha from ziddu. They got a quite good solution. BUT you must input it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to CURL the Captcha image in a php file.

add these two lines to help show the captcha image.
`ob_clean();` //to clean the output buffer so the image doesnt contain errors

```
header("Content-type:image/png");
```

Later using html"`img src`"tag to display the captcha in the user input form.
Hope it helps.